# Python on Netbeans 7.1

Tags: python, plugins, netbeans, installation

I've tried to find a plugin for this, but couldn't.

I also tried to follow these instructions to manually install it, but the link is dead.

https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/sturnbu/2011/05/12/netbeans-7-and-python-ide

Is there any other way to install it or is it not possible in netbeans 7.1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following link should work (add it into your plugin repository list as said in your given [source](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/sturnbu/2011/05/12/netbeans-7-and-python-ide)):
http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

But keep in mind that the Python Plugin is still buggy for Netbeans 7.* :
http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall

Good luck!

Comment: wow thanks for the link, the one in the guide was outdated probably.

Answer (score 5):

Are you wedded to netbeans?

If not, can I suggest PyCharm.

Comment: Yes we are Wedded to Netbeans, because its Absolutely Free/Complete unlike other commercial IDE... Note: PyCharm its not free if you plain to make your app for sell :3

Comment: If you're in this game for profit then there's better IDE's than netbeans.  If your developing in your spare time with a view to (maybe) selling in the future then try pycharm and update if you strike it rich.  I code for educational purposes so there is no money in my future.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide a more generic answer regarding modules installation.

It is possible to install a standalone module, to do so :

Go to **Tools-->Plugins-->Downloaded-->Add Plugin**

The plugin extension should be **nbm or jar**